# fastai conv_learner question import error problem

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, fast-ai

```
#from fastai.conv_learner import *
#from fastai.dataset import *
```

I'm having a problem with importing 
the version I use for fastai is

> Successfully installed fastai-1.0.60 fastprogress-0.2.2

Comment: I don't understand why Keras is present in your tags. Also, please provide your error message and a more detailed description of what happened.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?  https://www.reddit.com/r/learnmachinelearning/comments/a3jjvg/ive_started_working_with_fastai_but_i_cant_import/

Or maybe this?  https://github.com/fastai/fastai/issues/1134